# Issue with incrementing quantity in shopping cart

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I'm working on a Flutter application where I'm using the Provider package for state management. I have a shopping cart feature where users can add items to their cart. Each item is represented by a ProductModel class, which includes a quantity property to track the number of items in the cart. I want when an item is  already in the cart, it should increment the quantity in the shopping cart icon but I'm encountering an issue where the quantity is not increment in the shopping cart icon

```
class ProductModel {
  double? price;
  int? productId;
  int quantity;

  ProductModel({
    this.price,
    this.productId,
    this.quantity = 1,
  });
}
```

Here is the Provider

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../model/product_model.dart';

class ShoppingCartService extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<ProductModel> products = [];

  void addToCart(ProductModel item) {

    if (products.contains(item)) {
      int index = products.indexOf(item);
      products[index].quantity++;
    } else {
      products.insert(0,item);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  //remove from cart
  void removeFromCart(ProductModel itemRemove) {
    products.remove(itemRemove);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  //Total items in the cart
  int numberOfItemsInCart() {
    return products.length;
  }

  String getItemOrItems() {
    if (numberOfItemsInCart() == 1) {
      return 'item';
    } else {
      return 'items';
    }
  }

  //Get total price of the product in the cart
  double getTotalPrice() {
    double cartTotal = 0.0;
    for (ProductModel product in products) {
      cartTotal += product.price!;
    }
    return cartTotal;
  }
}
```

Here's the code snippet I'm using to display the quantity in a widget

```
return Consumer<ShoppingCartService>(
  builder: (context, cartService, child) {
    if (cartService.products.isEmpty) {
      return const SizedBox();
    }
    return Positioned(
      left: 25,
      top: 5,
      child: Container(
        height: 15,
        width: 15,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: AppColors.kPrimaryColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            cartService.numberOfItemsInCart().toString(),
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 9, color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

The cartService.numberOfItemsInCart() method retrieves the quantity, but the issue is that the quantity is not updating as expected when items are added.